# spring-jpa: PropertyReferenceException: No property [save] found for type [PerfectionTask]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We are trying to upgrade spring-data-jpa from 1.10.0 to 2.3.2
After upgrading the versions in the pom.xml, facing the following error while trying to deploy the application (as a spring boot app)

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type PerfectionTask!
```

So as per my understanding of the error, the 'save' method is of the PerfectionTaskRepository, but spring is trying to find the 'save' method in the PerfectionTask entity, where it is obviously not there.
I am just not sure why is it trying to find save method in the entity

Here is the code snippets for the respective repositories :

BaseDefinitionRepository.java

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseDefinitionRepository<T , D extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, D>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    <S extends T> S save(S entity, RequestDetails requestDetails);
    <S extends T> S saveAndFlush(S entity, RequestDetails requestDetails);
    <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities, RequestDetails requestDetails);

}
```

BaseDefinitionRepositoryImpl.java

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public class BaseDefinitionRepositoryImpl<T, D extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, D> implements BaseDefinitionRepository<T, D> {

    public BaseDefinitionRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    public BaseDefinitionRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity, RequestDetails requestDetails) {
        return super.save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> S saveAndFlush(S entity, RequestDetails requestDetails) {
        return super.saveAndFlush(entity);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T>  List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities, RequestDetails requestDetails) {
        return super.saveAll(entities);
    }
}
```

PerfectionTaskRepository.java

```java
@Repository
public interface PerfectionTaskRepository extends BaseDefinitionRepository<PerfectionTask, Long> {
    
    PerfectionTask findByTmTaskId(String tmTaskId);

    List<PerfectionTask> findByTmTaskIdIn(List<String> tmTaskId);
}
```

Entire stack trace of the error during deployment:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'perfectionTaskRepository' defined in <package-path>.repository.datamodel.PerfectionTaskRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on WebAppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Object <package-path>.repository.definition.BaseDefinitionRepository.saveAndFlush(java.lang.Object,<package-path>.repository.definition.RequestDetails)! No property save found for type PerfectionTask!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Object <package-path>.repository.definition.BaseDefinitionRepository.saveAndFlush(java.lang.Object,<package-path>.repository.definition.RequestDetails)! No property save found for type PerfectionTask!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:218) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type PerfectionTask!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:82) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 95 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You are upgrading from Spring Boot 2.0.7 to 2.3.2 NOT spring data JPA (which has a different versioning scheme). Make sure that your custom implementation is properly detected by Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, The version for spring-data-jpa in my pom.xml is 2.3.2.RELEASE
And yes, that has been upgraded as part of spring-boot upgradation.
But not sure how to resolve this error

Comment: No it isn't the version of the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is 2.3.2 (which is a spring boot starter managing the Spring Data JPA version for you!). if you are having that version for Spring Data jpa your situation is even worse and you are mixing old versions with new stuff.

Comment: And the versioning scheme seems to be correct - 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: The fact that you are using Spring Boot should make you NOT want to manage your own Spring Data JPA version (nor should you in that case) as that will eventually lead to you mixing jars of different versions (or incompatible versions) of a framework. According to your tags you are using Spring Boot, so are you really?

Comment: Yes, I am using spring boot. So as per your suggestion, I removed all the spring-data-jpa dependencies from my pom files, and did a fresh clean install and tried to deploy. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: You are using the `spring-boot-data-jpa` starter? And have upgraded the Spring Boot version? Instead of blindly upgrading 3 versions have you read the migration guides of all those versions (2.1, 2.2 and 2.3?). I wold suggest upgrading 1 version at a time and fix the issues along the line.

Comment: You don't need `BaseDefinitionRepositoryImpl`. Use default interface methods

Answer (score 1):

As described in [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository), you need to make Spring Data JPA aware of your base repository implementation by using `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = …)` explicitly.

Otherwise, `SimpleJpaRepository` will be used and the methods you have declared on your `BaseDefinitionRepository` will be interpreted as query methods and Spring Data will try to parse them as such, which leads to the exception you see.

That said, it's not entirely clear to me why you're trying to extend the base class in the first place as the implementation doesn't really make use of the additional parameters (yet?). I assume that's due to the state of the example, i.e. you were trying to get it started first and are not really done yet?

Answer (score 0):

## Rename the offending `save`

We had a collision in method naming. We were trying to overload "save" to work for a single item as well as for a collection. So we had an interface in between the Repository and our repositories to define both methods:

```
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BasePersistable, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

    T save(T persisted);

    Iterable<T> save(Iterable<T> persisted);
}
```

And the exception came for the collection saving method. So what we did was to rename the collection method from `save` to `saveAll` and the exception disappeared.

```
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BasePersistable, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

    T save(T persisted);

    Iterable<T> saveAll(Iterable<T> persisted);
}
```